# TypeError from screenfull library during jest test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I've added screenfull, a wrapper for the Fullscreen API (https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js) to a Redux-connected React component. The application uses Typescript elsewhere, but not in the components. Screenfull is used as follows in the component:

```
componentDidUnmount() {
  screenfull.on('change', () => this.props.toggleFullscreen());
}

componentWillUnmount() {
 screenfull.off('change', () => this.props.toggleFullscreen());
}
```

and I have a test as follows (there are more failing in the component test file, but I thought I'd share the first one)

```
  it('mounts with initial state', () => {
    const store = configureStore(reducer);
    const container = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <VideoBoundingBoxApp inIframe={false} />
      </Provider>);
    expect(container.find('VideoBoundingBoxApp')).toExist();
  });
```

The application runs and works as expected, but when running `yarn test`, I get the following error:

```
console.error node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
      Error: Uncaught [TypeError: _screenfull2.default.on is not a function]
          at reportException (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)
          at invokeEventListeners (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:209:9)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:119:9)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:82:17)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLElement-impl.js:30:27)
          at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:157:21)
          at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:944:16)
          at invokeGuardedCallback (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:993:29)
          at commitRoot (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7157:9)
          at completeRoot (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8065:36) TypeError: _screenfull2.default.on is not a function
          at VideoBoundingBoxApp.componentDidMount (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/src/components/VideoBoundingBox/VideoBoundingBoxApp.jsx:122:28)
          at commitLifeCycles (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:5347:26)
          at commitAllLifeCycles (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7018:9)
          at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:906:14)
          at invokeEventListeners (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:193:27)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:119:9)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:82:17)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLElement-impl.js:30:27)
          at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:157:21)
          at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:944:16)
          at invokeGuardedCallback (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:993:29)
          at commitRoot (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7157:9)
          at completeRoot (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8065:36)
          at performWorkOnRoot (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8015:11)
          at performWork (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7933:9)
          at performSyncWork (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7910:5)
          at requestWork (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7810:7)
          at scheduleWorkImpl (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7685:13)
          at scheduleWork (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7645:12)
          at scheduleRootUpdate (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8273:5)
          at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8301:12)
          at Object.updateContainer (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8328:14)
          at Object.create (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9009:18)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/src/test/components/VideoBoundingBox/VideoBoundingBoxApp.test.jsx:42:49)
          at Object.asyncFn (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine_async.js:82:37)
          at resolve (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:52:12)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
          at mapper (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:39:19)
          at promise.then (/Users/mschoemaker/Desktop/CrowdFlower/projects/image_annotation/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:73:82)
          at <anonymous>
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

(similar for screenfull.off...) I am not sure how to parse this. I don't think it's Typescript related. Would anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I (well, mostly my boss) figured it out. Turns out, the screenfull code has a check for whether `document` contains methods such as `requestFullscreen`, otherwise it returns false. I fixed this by adding

```
// fullscreen library will cause an error in jest tests
// if it  can't find fullscreen methods on document
[
  'requestFullscreen',
  'exitFullscreen',
].forEach(each => (document[each] = () => {})); // eslint-disable-line
```

to my `setupTests.js`

Comment: Hello, could you please elaborate your answer? I don't get where exactly place this code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Michel Schoemaker answer is correct, but I wanted to provide more context for those curious souls out there like myself. Thankfully, screenfull's source code is [super short and easy to reason about.](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/blob/master/dist/screenfull.js)

Looking at the source, you'll see a self-invoking function right at the top which stores its return value in a variable called `fn`.

```
    // This is what I'm talking about right here. See the end of this function
    var fn = (function () {
        var val;
        var fnMap = [
            [
                'requestFullscreen',
                'exitFullscreen',
                'fullscreenElement',
                'fullscreenEnabled',
                'fullscreenchange',
                'fullscreenerror'
            ],
            // New WebKit
            [
                'webkitRequestFullscreen',
                'webkitExitFullscreen',
                'webkitFullscreenElement',
                'webkitFullscreenEnabled',
                'webkitfullscreenchange',
                'webkitfullscreenerror'

            ],
            // Old WebKit
            [
                'webkitRequestFullScreen',
                'webkitCancelFullScreen',
                'webkitCurrentFullScreenElement',
                'webkitCancelFullScreen',
                'webkitfullscreenchange',
                'webkitfullscreenerror'

            ],
            [
                'mozRequestFullScreen',
                'mozCancelFullScreen',
                'mozFullScreenElement',
                'mozFullScreenEnabled',
                'mozfullscreenchange',
                'mozfullscreenerror'
            ],
            [
                'msRequestFullscreen',
                'msExitFullscreen',
                'msFullscreenElement',
                'msFullscreenEnabled',
                'MSFullscreenChange',
                'MSFullscreenError'
            ]
        ];

        var i = 0;
        var l = fnMap.length;
        var ret = {};
        // This for loop essentially checks the current document object for the property/methods above. 
        for (; i < l; i++) {
            val = fnMap[i];
            if (val && val[1] in document) {
                for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                    ret[fnMap[0][i]] = val[i];
                }
                return ret;
            }
        }
        // If it doesn't find any of them, this whole function returns false
        // and the fn variable is set to this returned value. 
        return false;
    })();
```

Then further down in the you'll see for a simple conditional check on this `fn` variable.

```
    // Sidenote, if you just remove the bang from the conditional, this package
    // works in testing. But obviously we don't want to do that. 
    if (!fn) {
        if (isCommonjs) {
            module.exports = {isEnabled: false};
            // If log out the value of screenfull after importing it 
            // in your test, this is what you'll see -> {isEnabled: false}
            // Thus screenfull sets this object as the exported module and returns early. 
        } else {
            window.screenfull = {isEnabled: false};
        }

        return;
    }
```

So back to @Michel Schoemaker's answer; The reason that works is because we're basically monkey patching these properties/methods in the document object so Screenfull thinks we have a compatible environment. Once it think's we have a compatible environment, Jest can mock the library as usual.

I did things a little different than @Michel Schoemaker because I was only using screenfull in two methods of my application so I didn't need to set them up for my whole testing environment. Here' my approach:

**thing.spec.js**

```
import screenfull from 'screenfull';

jest.mock('screenfull');

    //********* Fullscreen **********//
    describe('Fullscreen', () => {

        beforeEach(() => {
            document.requestFullscreen = jest.fn();
            document.exitFullscreen = jest.fn();
            document.fullscreenElement = jest.fn();
            document.fullscreenEnabled = jest.fn();
            document.fullscreenchange = jest.fn();
            document.fullscreenerror = jest.fn();
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            jest.clearAllMocks();
        });

        test('test name', (done) => {
            // Assemble

            // Act

            // Assert
            expect(screenfull.toggle).toHaveBeenCalled();
            done();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing in the unit test you likely want to `jest.mock` this dependency. 
And the `_screenfull2.default.on is not a function` error might be caused by mismatch between commonjs modules and es6 modules. How are you importing screenfull?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am importing it as `import screenfull from 'screenfull';`, just as all my other dependencies.

Comment: does it work outside of the unit test, when you manually test?

Comment: I've also tried `import * as screenfull from 'screenfull'`, and `const screenfull = require('screenfull')`, but I get the same error

Comment: if you don't have this error in actual application code, then maybe the problem lies in the way jest loads the module. Checkout http://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html#using-babel

Comment: you might also want to consider ts-jest